# How to remove month from year that was entered in as a str, in pandas?

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, datetime, integer

I have a series of year-month data that was written as:

```
2017-01
2018-02
2019-10
```

I want to remove the month and just have the year and convert it to an int, to do some basic subtraction. I do not need it to be a datetime object, how exactly do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

okay i have found a solution,

i just did this

`df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month']).dt.year`